# How can I disable notification for a specific gmail account during certain hours?

Tags: gmail, tasker

My work and personal emails are attached to my phone. I'd like to avoid getting any notifications of work emails after hours.

If this can be done with Tasker, I can't figure out how. I can disable notifications in the gmail settings manually, but not sure how to affect this setting with Tasker.

- I still want to receive notifications to my personal email
- I still want to receive notifications in general
- I still want my work email to sync (so I can check if I need you)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Toggling the syncing of Gmail for the account is the best option.  Turning of Gmail sync on a Google account in Android does not prevent you from fetching mail for that account via a method such as "pull to refresh" when you are viewing that account in the Gmail app.

I use Synker to integrate with Tasker, though I know there are other apps that expose Tasker control of specific sync settings on an account by account basis.

The basic outline I have is as follows:

- A profile named "Work" whose conditions are a combination of a time, 9am-5pm, and a Date, Mon-Fri.  It has the same entry and exit task.
- A task named "Work" that has two items: one to set the sync options of my work Google account to have Gmail sync on that is conditional on `if %PACTIVE ~ *Work*`, one to set the sync options of my work Google account to /not/ sync Gmail `if %PACTIVE !~ *Work*`

If I want to read work email when sync is not on for that account, I just open Gmail, switch to that account, and swipe down ("pull to refresh"), fetching the messages from the server.

Answer (score 6):

Try the app **Quiet for Gmail** from here https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sgarcia.quiet_for_gmail

It toggles the sync of your email accounts on a schedule you can define. In addition to that, you can also override your schedule for special occasions, like a bank holiday.

Comment: This is great, thanks. Really quick and easy.