# Disable gmail notifications for certain labels during certain hours

Tags: gmail, 4.3-jelly-bean

I want to shut off gmail notifications (not SMS or calls) for specific labels (not all labels) from 11 pm to 8:30 am every day.

[Turning off sync](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88909/how-can-i-disable-notification-for-a-specific-gmail-account-during-certain-hours) (or turning off all notifications) during those hours will not work, because I still need to get notifications for certain emails at all times.

Is there a way to do this? I don't see a way to do it in IFTT. Don't want to purchase a paid app unless I have confirmation that it will work.

My phone is encrypted and not rooted, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the app **Quiet for Gmail**, it will enable/disable the synchronization based on your schedule. And you set it up to disable synchronization just for your work email account and leave your personal email always on.

You can find the app here:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sgarcia.quiet_for_gmail